# How to formalize notion of "maximally dominated/dominating" probability?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request

I want to choose a probability measure on the measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ that dominates, or is dominated by, "as many probability measures as possible." The question is how to formalize the phrase that I placed in scare quotes.

I will give some simple examples to help show what I have in mind. ($P$ dominates $Q$ means $P(A)=0$ implies $Q(A)=0$, and we write $Q \ll P$.)

*"Maximally dominating" probabilities*. Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ is countable and assume $\mathcal{F}$ is the powerset of $\Omega$. If $P$ is a probability that assigns the singletons in $\mathcal{F}$ positive measure, then $P$ dominates every probability $Q$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$. So probabilities that assign positive measure to singletons are "maximally" dominating, they dominate "as many probabilities as possible."

Of course, for general $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ this won't work. Instead, I thought we could define a probability $P$ to be maximally dominating if there is no $Q$ such that 
$$\{\mu: \mu \ll Q \} \supset \{\mu: \mu \ll P \}.$$ 
This definition seems to pass some simple sanity checks. For example, point masses $\delta_\omega$ are not maximally dominating on this definition since $\{\mu: \mu \ll \delta_\omega \} = \{ \delta_\omega\}$, but any $Q$ with $Q(\{\omega \})>0$ dominates $\delta_\omega$ and many other probabilities as well. But I am unsure how to proceed from here; I don't have an example of a maximally dominating measure.

*"Maximally dominated" probabilities*. In this case, I don't really have any ideas. Even for countable $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$, we cannot hope to do what we did above: there's no probability that's dominated by *every* other probability (if we didn't require our measures to be probabilities, though, then the $0$ measure would be maximally dominated.)

To sum up,

> Are there any known formalisms for the notions I'm trying to capture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a poset of (equivalence classes of) probability measures.  For $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, let $P(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be the set of probability measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$.  For two measures $\mu, \nu \in (\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, say that $\mu \sim \nu$ if $\mu \ll \nu$ and $\nu \ll \mu$.  Then we can consider $P(\Omega,\mathcal{F})/\sim$ as a partially ordered set with partial ordering $\ll$.  Then a "maximally dominating" measure is simply one that is maximal in this poset, and a "maximally dominated" measure is one that is minimal in this poset.  For instance, if $\Omega = \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathcal{F} = 2^\mathbb{Z}$, then any probability measure supported on the entire set is maximal.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Can anything more be said about this partial ordering, or can you refer me to a work that studies it? For instance,  do you have an explicit example of a maximally dominated measure? Under what conditions do maximal/minimal measures exist?

Comment: I believe that the definition maximally dominating that I give in the question is equivalent to yours, but your setup is simpler and more elegant. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

This is an addendum to Marcus M's answer. I will give a characterization of maximal/minimal measures with respect to the partial order induced by $\ll$.

---

Let's say a measure is **strictly positive** if its only null set is the empty set.

Then the following is true:

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space. Then a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ is maximal if and only if it is strictly positive.

*Proof:*

1. Let $\mu$ be strictly positive. Let $\nu$ be a probability measure such that $\mu \ll \nu$. Then $\nu$ is also strictly positive, so $\nu \sim \mu$. Thus $\mu$ is maximal.
2. Assume that $\mu$ is not strictly positive. Then there is some non-empty set $A \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\mu(A) =0$. Take a point $x \in A$ and take $\nu$ to be the Dirac measure centered at $x$.
   Now, consider the probability measure $\rho = \mu/2 + \nu/2$. Then $\mu \ll \rho$, but $\rho$ and $\mu$ are not equivalent since $\rho(A) = 1/2$, while $\mu(A) =0$. Therefore, we have shown that $\mu$ is not maximal.

---

Now let's characterize the minimal measures. As suggested by Aduh in the comments, those are the measures that take only the values $0$ and $1$:

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space. Then
>    a measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ is minimal if and only if it is $0-1$ valued.

*Proof:*

1. $0-1$ valued $\Rightarrow$ minimal.

Assume that $\mu$ is not minimal. This means there exists a probability measure $\nu$ with $\nu \ll \mu$ and $\nu \nsim \mu$. Thus there is a measurable set $F$ such that $\nu(F) =0$ and $\mu(F) > 0$. Then $\nu(\Omega \setminus F) =1$ since $\nu$ is a probability. This implies that $\mu(\Omega \setminus F) > 0$ since $\nu \ll \mu$. Thus we obtain that
$$
\mu(F) + \mu( \Omega \setminus F) = 1
$$
with both $\mu(F)$ and $\mu( \Omega \setminus F)$ strictly positive. Thus $\mu$ cannot be $0-1$ valued.

2. Minimal $\Rightarrow$ $0-1$ valued.

Assume $\mu$ is not $0-1$ valued. There is a measurable set $A$ with $0< \mu(A) <1$. The complement $A^c$ also satisfies $0 < \mu(A ^c) <1$. Define the measure $\nu$ to be the conditional probability with respect to $A$:
$$
\nu(F) = \frac{ \mu( F \cap A)}{\mu(A)}
$$
Then $\nu \ll \mu$ since $\mu(F) =0$ implies $\mu(F\cap A) =0$. However, $\nu$ and $\mu$ are not equivalent since $\nu( A^c) =0$ while $\mu(A^c) >0$. Therefore, $\mu$ is not minimal.

Comment: For the converse, does this work? Assume $\mu$ is not 0-1 valued. Let $A_0 \in \{ A \in \mathcal{F}:  0 < P(A) < 1\}$. Let $\nu = \mu(\cdot \mid A_0^c)$ and $$\rho = \frac{\mu \wedge \nu}{(\mu \wedge \nu)(\Omega)}.$$ I believe $\mu \wedge \nu \neq 0$, $\rho \ll \mu$ and $\rho \not \sim \mu$ because $\mu(A_0) > 0$ but $\rho(A_0)=0$. So $\mu$ isn't minimal. If this works, we don't need to assume anything about atoms in $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: I'm not really convinced that $\mu \wedge \nu$ should be non-zero. However, the idea to use conditional probability is great and it suffices to consider $\nu$: see my updated answer. This makes me even more suspicious of all the fuss about atomic sigma algebras for the maximal ones... there's probably a way to overcome this. By the way, it might be a good idea to create a separate question about the characterization of minimal/maximal measures, since your initial question is rather different.

Comment: Originally, I was thinking $(\mu \wedge \nu)(\Omega)>0$, but now I'm also not convinced (the strict equality could get lost after taking the infimum). Anyway, your suggestion is better. I will consider making a new question, thanks.

Comment: Here's an idea to simplify the first proof. Assume $\mu$ is not strictly positive and $\mu(A)=0$. Let $\rho$ be any probability with $\rho(A)>0$ (can I assume this exists?), and $\nu = \mu/2 +\rho/2$. Then $\mu \ll \nu$ and $\nu \not \sim \mu$.

Comment: @aduh Thank you for the generous bounty. I feel like I have been quite misleading. I hope I didn't cause too much confusion and that everything is clear now.